# How to apply cls in extjs tagfield

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs6

I have one extjs tagfield and i am using `grow : false,` by which I can restrict the vertical grow of field.[MyFiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h89)

I want to add element in tagfield horizentally not vertically. Also When size is increase parent(on which tagfield is placed) size is also increase. I want to not to increase parent size. Tagfield hright should independent from parent width.

Current when Item selected it is appearing as a box, I want to use my own css. How to apply css in tagfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can add config in  your tag field:

```
formItemCls:'your class name'
```

Comment: Follow this link for more information :http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#cfg-formItemCls